# Get owner ids of all servers bot is in

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command for my discord bot that dms all the server owners.
I am able to get the owner id of the server that the message is sent in with:

```
message.guild.ownerID
```

I need some way to get the owner ids for every server the bot is active in

Answer (score 0):

To print out the owner id of each guild that your bot is in:

```js
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => console.log(guild.ownerID));
```

To dm all the owners:

```js
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
       guild.member(guild.ownerID).user.send('Hello owner of: ' + guild.name);
    });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited it a little, hopefully it's better now.